# How do I disable the IIS server on Windows 10 and free up port 80?

Tags: windows-10, iis

I want to use [TiKi](https://tiki.org/HomePage) to use as a collaboration website.

Up until Windows 10 arrived I've never had any trouble installing development tools using the LAMPP, WAMPP, or XAMPP website installers. Tools such as Redmine, TestLink, CMS, and others. Now Windows 10 installs and activates IIS whether you want it or not. Consequently, it hogs port 80 which impacts connections to MySQL and other modules down the line.

I changed Apache to use Port 8080 instead of 80 as IIS is sitting on 80. That worked for Apache, except now it package couldn't find MySQL on Port 3306 or PHP.

How do I completely disable IIS server and everything it is now hogging?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you've got a couple of distinct questions- disabling IIS, and sorting out MySQL and PHP. I would recommend that you [edit] your question and focus on one thing at a time, such as disabling IIS. You can then [ask] a separate question with more details about MySQL and one for PHP if needed at that point. Cheers! :)

Comment: “Now Windows 10 installs and activates IIS whether you want it or not.” – It most certainly does not. You might want to check [my answer] on a related question.

Comment: @DanielB you omitted the link- I would add it myself but I wasn't sure which one of your 859 answers it was :)

Comment: Whoops. P: [Here’s the answer](https://superuser.com/a/726975/219095), this time for real. :)

Comment: Where have you "tried" to install Apache/XAMPP? As I understand it, there can be permissions issues if installing to the `Program Files` directory. (?)

Comment: In my case it was about SQL Server 2014 Express, I had to stop it's service in order to be able to run apache in XAMPP.

Answer (score 19):

To uninstall IIS:

- Call *Control Panel > Programs and Features*
- Click *Turn Windows features on or off*
- Scroll down to *Internet Information Services*

  [image]
- Click on the square next to *Internet Information Services* so it becomes empty

  [image]
- Click OK and reboot if required.

Comment: "Uninstalling" would seem to be a bit overkill IMO. Can the "service"(?) not be simply stopped? (Or change the port that IIS listens on?)

Comment: @MrWhite You stop all related services, but Windows has a nag for turning them back on after updates.

Comment: still IIS is running and port 80 is blocked...

Comment: This is uninstalling IIS, not disabling IIS.  MegamanHxH answer is the correct one

Comment: worked like a charm for me , thanks!

Answer (score 18):

> ### W3SVC
>
> The World Wide Web Publishing service, described in detail here, is a listener adapter for http.sys. The W3SVC service can be stopped and started from the Services management console.
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/16/lab-6-using-http-w3svc-was-and-w3wp/

You can disable the W3SVC service by running the command

```
services.msc
```

Search for "World Wide Web Publishing Service", Double-click to access the service's properties. And finally change Startup type from "Automatic" to "Manual" or "Disabled".

However, this will disable it until the next update comes, Windows will reset the settings based on [Matt](https://superuser.com/questions/1377068/how-do-i-disable-the-iis-server-on-windows-10-and-free-up-port-80?newreg=8bf7078b77ae43ffae7b4b2c406190c0#comment2130424_1377078) comment.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the Web Server IIS:

1. press (win + x)
2. open Windows PowerShell (admin)
3. type:  "net stop WAS"  and press ENTER

more info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj635851(v=ws.11)

Comment: After pressing win+x, I don't get an option for PowerShell. There's only Command Prompt for me

Comment: with command prompt (admin
) should work too

Answer (score 0):

why not just stop the sites from running in IIS? that worked for me. I.e. in IIS Manager select the Default Web Site and click on Stop in the right hand side bar under Manage Website.